# notepad++ regex replace without loosing search criteria

Tags: notepad++, regex

"@Deprecated" code should not be used111 Synchronized classes Vector, Hashtable, Stack and StringBuffer should not be used67 Class variable fields should not have public accessibility56 Methods should not be empty52

I have above text and want to add Tab everywhere i found combination of letter and number without space. then Add new line at end of each number found with Space. below is how it should look like.
I am trying this in Notepad++. I can do search to find letter concatenated with number using [a-z][0-9] but wondering how can i do replace without losing the qualified letters in end result

"@Deprecated" code should not be used     111
Synchronized classes Vector, Hashtable, Stack and StringBuffer should not be used     67
Class variable fields should not have public accessibility56 Methods should not be empty     52

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are a community of people interested in computers, not a free coding service. If you already have tried something please post it, this way it is easier for us to provide you with a helpful answer. Otherwise you will probably not get an answer to your question.

Comment: You should format your question to be more readable, but I think you *might* be looking for **Find what:** `\s(\w+\d+)\s` and **Replace with:** `\t\1\r\n`  You can swap-out `\s` in the Find what with a space character ( ) to be more accurate.